# Dsiplaying status bar, then hiding it on button press

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` subclass that currently displays a status bar. In `viewDidLoad` I call the following:

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

And then I have also implemented this statement:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

When a user taps a button, I call a method that displays a `UIView` subclass that I have created. All the method does is tell the subclass to set it's `alpha` property to 1 so that it will appear on screen.

My problem is, I want to hide the status bar whenever I display this `UIView` subclass.

I have tried calling the following in both the controller and the view subclass:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

The status bar never hides. Obviously I can't use the regular methods like the following because then it will hide the status bar in the controller altogether, and I only want it to hide when I display the view subclass:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
          return YES;
  }
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? I am using nib files to represent the `UIViewController` and `UIView` by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just create a property and override its setter, for example:

(in interface)

`@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL statusBarHidden;`

(in implementation)

```
- (void)setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)statusBarHidden
{
   if (_statusBarHidden != statusBarHidden)
   {
      _statusBarHidden = statusBarHidden;
      [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
   }
}
```

and set it as needed.

Then modify the status bar hidden view controller method like this:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
   return self.statusBarHidden;
}
```

Comment: That's a great idea, and one that I was already planning on implementing if nothing else was posted. I guess I assumed I was doing something wrong by approaching it that way, and that there was possibly a method I could call to make it all work perfectly.

Comment: Well, you could make a custom subclass of UIViewController and implement this functionality for all view controllers that inherit from it, or you could even create a category where you could add properties using objc runtime and then overriding the setters and getters (so you could still make your classes inherit from UIViewController). But I agree that all of them look kinda hacky and there is really no "one-liner"/simple solution :)

Comment: Your solution is the easiest to implement and makes the most sense. Cheers!